# Else if loop with try

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

So i am trying to create a set of validation for user inputs in which the input box must have an input entered and be a positive integer greater than 0. I get syntax errors around the elif parts, any help on how to format this correctly would be helpful

```
def MDConfirm_btn_clicked(self,MGStudent_drop):
   ##Max marks input
   Max_marks=(self.MDMax_inp.text())

   if len(str(Max_marks))==0: #check if length is the same as 0
       Presence_error_open.show()#call presence error prompt if condtion is met

   elif: 
      try:   
        Max_marks=int(self.MDMax_inp.text()) #take input from maximim  marks entry  
      except ValueError:#if python detects error in value type flag error
          Char_error_open.show()       

   elif int((Max_marks)) <=0: #check is value is less than 0
      Char_error_open.show()

   else:
       Max_marks=m1
```

Comment: An `elif` needs to come with a condition, just like `if`.

Comment: @KlausD.  how would i enter implement the try part though, it wont run when i try put it on the same line

Comment: You need to restructure the logic here. Try moving the try/except outside the if/elif/else block to build a value and then use that value in the elif condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try restructuring like ths:

```
def MDConfirm_btn_clicked(self, MGStudent_drop):
   Max_marks = self.MDMax_inp.text()
   if not Max_marks:
       Presence_error_open.show()
   else:
        try:   
            Max_marks = int(Max_marks)
            if Max_marks < 0:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            Char_error_open.show()
        else:
            Max_marks = m1
```

(NB: I assumed `Max_marks` should be less than zero, rather than equal to or less than zero, as you currently have it).

However, I think it would be better to [set a validator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#setValidator) on the line-edit, as this would simply prevent incorrect values being entered in the first place. The built-in [QIntValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qintvalidator.html) seems to do exactly what you want.